# Android VideoView is not playing video from internel memory

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have developed an application to play video.I used VideoView view play the Video.It is working fine to play a video from url.But when I am trying to play a video from Internal memory means (app memory), it always shows the following dialog[image]

I am getting this in log cat

```
11-28 12:09:22.171: E/MediaPlayer(4862): error (1, -2147483648)
11-28 12:09:22.292: E/MediaPlayer(4862): Error (1,-2147483648)
11-28 12:09:22.292: D/VideoView(4862): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Any one help me in this

Answer (score 0):

On many older phones, pre Android 4.0, videos needed to be written world readable to be played  even from an apps internal files directory.

Comment: But it playing in Medida player not in video view